# Retrieve a value of Smarty variable whose name consists of variables

Tags: php, smarty

I have a set of arrays of php variables that are assigned into SMARTY template. The following is the php variable:

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i) {
  ${'field'.$i} = array('group_rank_edit_' . $i, 'some_data'.$i);

  // Assign variable to the template
  $smarty->assign('field'.$i , ${'field'.$i});
}
```

So there are 3 arrays that are assigned to the template. Now, in the template I have difficulties on retrieving the values. Suppose the template is kinda like this:

```
{{for $i=1 to 3}}
  $().ready(function() {
    $("#group-ranks-edit-form").validate({
        rules: {
           {{$field.{{$i}}.0}}: {
                required: true,
            }
        },
     });
});
{{/for}}
```

So that one of the output will look like this:

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#group-ranks-edit-form").validate({
        rules: {
          group_rank_edit_1 : {
                required: true,
            }
        },
     });
});
```

Clearly the following format doesn't result the intended output:

```
{{$field.{{$i}}.0}}
```

Any ideas? I'm using Smarty 3 BTW.

Much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store your fields in just one array (PHP) an iterate over it (Smarty) by using foreach.

**PHP**

```
$smarty = new Smarty;
$f      = [];                // array will contain data of all 3 fields
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; ++$i)  // fill array with data
{
    $f[$i] = array('group_rank_edit_' . $i, 'some_data'.$i);
}
$smarty->assign('f' , $f);   // assign the array to smarty
```

**Smarty**

```
{foreach from=$f key=i item=data}
    {literal}
        $().ready(function() {
            $("#group-ranks-edit-form").validate({
                rules:
    {/literal}
                    {$data.0}:
    {literal}
                    {
                        required: true,
                    }
                },
            });
        });
    {/literal}
{/foreach}
```

**Output generated by Smarty**

```
$().ready(function() {
    $("#group-ranks-edit-form").validate({
        rules:
            group_rank_edit_1:
            {
                required: true,
            }
        },
    });
});

$().ready(function() {
    $("#group-ranks-edit-form").validate({
        rules:
            group_rank_edit_2:
            {
                required: true,
            }
        },
    });
});

$().ready(function() {
    $("#group-ranks-edit-form").validate({
        rules:
            group_rank_edit_3:
            {
                required: true,
            }
        },
    });
});
```